# missing ; error in google sheet script

Tags: excel, google-sheets

following code works in excel but dosent work in google sheets. it says ; is missing before statement in line 2. where to put the ; in the code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column <> 1 Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" And Target.Value > "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("B:B")) + 1
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you expect that to work in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Google sheets uses the Javascript language for working with spreadsheets programmatically, and Excel uses Visual Basic for Applications (VBA for short).

- Here's some info on how to use code to drive Google Sheets: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- And some info for how to use VBA with Excel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Your question is kind of like asking, "When I plug my XBox controller into the USB port in my car, why doesn't it control the car the same as when I play Forza Motorsport?" :)